# Combine two ggplots without interfering the aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

Plot 1:

```
g1 = ggplot(path[order(path$order),], aes(PC1, PC2)) + geom_point(aes(color=position, size=path_size)) + 
geom_text(aes(label=order, vjust=2)) + geom_path() + xlim(0,0.03) + ylim(-0.03,0.03)
```

[image]

Ideally I'd like to make the START and END positions of the path a different color/shape/size to make it look distinct.

Plot 2:

```
g2 = ggplot(d, (aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=CellType))) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Plot 1 is a directed path through a subset of points from plot 2. I'm not sure how to combine these two plots without interfering with the aesthetics. A snipped of the data used to generate each plots is shown below:

```
path = d[as.vector(colnames(adj)), 1:2]
path$order = seq(1:nrow(path))
path$position = as.factor(ifelse(path$order == 1, "START", ifelse(path$order == nrow(path), "END", "PATH")))
path_size = as.factor(ifelse(path$order == 1, 2, ifelse(path$order == nrow(path), 2, 1)))



> head(path)
                                     PC1        PC2 order position
D6_NoSort2250b_TGTCCCCCACTC   0.02303190 0.01264362     1    START
D6_NoSort6000b_TTCTTTAACCCC   0.01054032 0.02401583     2     PATH
D6_EcadSort2250b_ACGGTTTGGCTT 0.01548174 0.02315813     3     PATH
D6_EcadSort2250b_CAGCCCGCTATT 0.02263683 0.01523706     4     PATH
D6_NoSort2250b_GACAGCACGTCT   0.02262139 0.01252870     5     PATH
D6_NoSort2250b_CCAGCACGGTAA   0.01986103 0.01584703     6     PATH

> head(d[,1:2])
                                    PC1         PC2
MEF_23x2cycGelX_ACCTAAGTTACC 0.01394239 0.003256282
MEF_18cycGelX_TGGACTATCTAG   0.01368773 0.009878876
MEF_18cycGelX_GGATACCCGCTT   0.01423563 0.010897071
MEF_18cycGelX_CTTTCAGCGCTC   0.01315417 0.012731415
MEF_18x2cycGelX_GCAGGTTCATTT 0.01318875 0.013687629
MEF_18cycGelX_CTTTCGTCCTGC   0.01102215 0.013257857
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Updated code

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea for combining the two plots which will result in the plot shown below. Basically, the key is to specify the data for the non-path plot separately in the geom_point function. Also, I added a shape parameter to the path points to achieve the "the START and END positions of the path a different ...shape"

```
library(ggplot2)
path <- data.frame(PC1=c(0.02303190,0.01054032,0.01548174,0.02263683,0.02262139,0.01986103),
                   PC2=c(0.01264362,0.02401583,0.02315813,0.01523706,0.01252870,0.01584703),
                   order=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
path$color = as.factor(ifelse(path$order == 1, "START", ifelse(path$order == nrow(path), "END", "PATH")))

d <- data.frame(PC1=c(0.01394239,0.01368773,0.01423563,0.01315417,0.01318875,0.01102215),
                PC2=c(0.003256282,0.009878876,0.010897071,0.012731415,0.013687629,0.013257857),
                cellType=c("D6", "ESC", "MEF", "D6", "ESC", "MEF"))


g2 = ggplot(path[order(path$order),], aes(PC1, PC2)) + 
  geom_point(data=d, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=cellType)) +
  geom_point(aes(PC1, PC2, shape=color), color="black") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=order, vjust=2)) + geom_path()
g2
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this works. Would it be possible to make the points on the path an ombre/spectrum from green (START) to red (END) and not include this information in the legend? I can't seem to even make the points in the path black (`.. geom_point(aes(PC1, PC2, color="black", shape=position)) + ` doesn't work).

Comment: When setting properties to constant values, you should pull them out of the aesthetic and set them as separate parameters as in: geom_point(aes(PC1, PC2, shape=position), color="black"). For the spectrum, this gets into a scale_colour_gradient. I'm not sure how to do that on a combined plot though, and keep (prevent) the d points from using the gradient as well.